# Почему метод с запросом перестаёт работать?

Tags: c#

Я в ListView записываю результат запроса, он работает . Выводит все те данные которые мне необходимо

Но в событии tbPoisk_TextChanged возникает исключение

***System.NotSupportedException: "Выражению LINQ to Entities не удается распознать метод "Boolean ListViewDate(System.String)", поэтому его нельзя преобразовать в выражение хранилища."***

Почему метод в событии не хочет коректно работать ?

```
    public BookPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ListViewDate(sql);
    }

    const string sql = "SELECT * FROM books " +
           "WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL " +
                 "FROM Extraditions " +
                  "WHERE Extraditions.IdBook = Books.Id " +
                    "AND Extraditions.IdStatus <> 2)";
   
    public bool ListViewDate(string sql)
    {            
      var  book = App.DataBase.Books.
        SqlQuery(sql).ToList();
        listBook.ItemsSource = book;
        return true;
    }      

    private void tbPoisk_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbPoisk.Text))
        {
            try
            {
                listBook.ItemsSource = App.DataBase.Books.Where(p => ListViewDate(sql) && (

                p.NameBook.ToString().ToLower().Contains(tbPoisk.Text.ToLower()) ||
                p.AuthorOfThebook.ToString().ToLower().Contains(tbPoisk.Text.ToLower()) ||
                p.YearOfPublication.ToString().ToLower().Contains(tbPoisk.Text.ToLower()))).ToList();

                var rows = listBook.ItemsSource.Cast<Book>().ToList();
                if (rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    tbInfo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                if (rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    tbInfo.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                tbInfo.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка в получении данных", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                tbInfo.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                ListViewDate(sql);
            }
            catch
            {
                tbInfo.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка в получении данных", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте сделать `.ToList()` перед этим проблемным `.Where()`

Comment: Я только не понял - вы в этой функции меняете источник той коллекции, к которой эта функция применяется?! Как-то очень хитро выглядит.

Comment: @CrazyElf, Ну я просто хочу что бы поиск был исключительно с теми данными , который метод ListViewDate выводит,  а так если уберу его, он начнет поиск бить по всем записям из таблицы, поэтому  я 
и пихаю ему метод . Но не хочет с ним в месте работать .

Comment: @CrazyElf, добавил перед where   ToList начал хоть что то искать. Но по каким то причинам может выдаст записи, которые не удовлетворяют запросу в методе ListViewDate

Answer (score 0):

Метод boolen возвращает 2 варианта либо true либо false

Comment: ListViewDate(sql); сделайте проверку для этой строчки если true то ок, иначе … то-то

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. и опечатки стоит исправлять.